# Access iframe window object within parent DOM

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have project in which I have an  elements from other domains. I'm using JavaScript to access first iframe window object into variable. Here is code :

```
var iframes = window.frames;

//grab first iframe
var ifrWindow = iframes[0].window;  // Here is where I get **Permision denied**

ifrWindow.postMessage("hello",IframeDomain);
```

I'm getting 'Permission denied' only for IE8. I have no problems with Chrome, Firefox, Safari or later versions IE11, etc..

Anyone has experienced this kind of issue with IE8?

Comment: does contentWindow work instead of just window?

Comment: Thanks danavis! contentWindow works with IE8!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried contentWindow or contentDocument method?

Something like this should work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
var iframeWindow = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
```