# How do I put an HTML over Youtube iframe using javascript

Tags: youtube-api

How can I access the iframe of a youtube video and use it to layer an html over it? Right now as I access the contentDocument I get a CORS error. Please help if can, below is a code snippet

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var iframe = player.getIframe();
  var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
  var pops = document.createElement('div');
  pops.innerHTML =
  '<div class="bar">' +
  '</div>';
  iframe.appendChild(pops)
  event.target.playVideo();
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access iframe window object within parent DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351786/access-iframe-window-object-within-parent-dom)

Comment: No, when trying to do that I still get this error Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame... any other suggestions? I want to be able to access the youtube iFrame so that Ican layer over it. Thanks